# Ubuntu 12.04 Windows Snap Feature

Tags: 12.04, installation, updates, lts

When I first installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 32.bit from a Live-CD without internet connection and any updates the snapping feature worked fine for windows of all applications. However, after some updates and installations it stopped working. I can no longer drag a window to the edge of the screen and have it resized. Thinking the problem is from my lack of experience I did a clean install of Ubuntu 12.04 again with internet connection; however, the problem still persists and I am fed up with this. Do you have any suggestions for remedy? Thanks in advance.

P.S: The feature when working properly was just like that in Windows 7. I am a new user BTW so I might be skipping some important details, and I would be glad if you can remind me of them.

Answer (score 7):

First you should make sure Compiz is running. In a terminal type:

```
ps -A | grep compiz
```

If there is no output, you have a bigger problem and you need to properly configure your graphics card.  Try running `jockey` in dash and installing proprietary drivers if you need them. If you are using a laptop with Nvidia Optimus card, look into the bumblebee project: http://bumblebee-project.org/

Further graphics card troubleshooting is beyond the scope of this answer.

If Compiz is running and you still don't get the snap feature:
Install Compiz Configuration Settings Manager (ccsm) either through the software center or by:

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

Open up ccsm (you can just type it in the dash).

Go to the Window Management Section and make sure that `Grid` is checked:
[image]

If you open Grid, you can choose the `Edges` Tab and alter the settings there:
[image]

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work.

Comment: Can you confirm that you are in Unity and not Unity 2D? One way to check is to go to a terminal and type `ps -A | grep compiz`. If compiz is not running then this feature won't work and more likely you are having graphic card setup issues

Comment: That does not yield any output, how can I configure my graphics card, Nvidia GT540M, then?

Comment: Edited the answer to give some hints, but graphic card problems can be tricky and I'm no expert

Comment: Hmm still not working.

Comment: @Vesnog - You'll have to install your Nvidia drivers. You can do this by going to the "Drivers" tab of "Additional Software Sources". If you've updated, you should see a list of three or four graphics drivers (if not, make sure the restricted/proprietary repositories are checks and update apt). Make sure one of the Nvidia ones are selected and relog. Once you get the drivers installed, you should be able to follow Ian's instructions.