# How to get Snap Assist like feature on 14.04?

Tags: 14.04

Microsoft introduces Snap assist feature since windows 10, is there a way to get similar feature on 14.04?

**SNAP ASSIST:**
Assume I have N windows open, randomly scattered all over my desktop and workspaces. Now I scale one such window to, say, the right half of the screen. As soon as I do that, all the remaining windows would form an expose of the left half, when I click one of those left half windows it will take up the LEFT half of the screen automatically.

Comment: Many of us are no Windows 10 users and might therefore not know (and not want to google) what you mean by "Snap assist". Would you mind [edit]ing your question and describing the feature? Thanks.

Comment: ehm this? http://askubuntu.com/questions/507212/ubuntu-14-04-snap-to-1-4-of-the-screen-instead-of-1-2 or ... http://askubuntu.com/questions/199688/ubuntu-12-04-windows-snap-feature We have had a "snap" feature since well before 2012. No idea if is the W10 thingy though ;-)

Comment: like this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AGnfaAou4d8 @Rinzwind

Comment: "Snap assist" (Windows-10) is the evolution of  Aerosnap (Windows-7)and is the superset of Aerosnap functionality.